# Filtering Content Editor global search in SOLR

Tags: content-search, solr

When I use the global search in the Content Editor in my Sitecore 8.1 instance (that uses Lucene), the search.log displays the following output:

```
ExecuteQueryAgainstLucene (sitecore_master_index): spanFirst(SpanWildcardQuery(_name:searchterm*), 1) (+SpanWildcardQuery(_content:*searchterm*) +_language:en) - Filter : 
ExecuteQueryAgainstLucene (sitecore_testing_index): host:4b75d9f9081d4232b55e5b7b845b5119en - Filter : 
ExecuteQueryAgainstLucene (sitecore_testing_index): +host:4b75d9f9081d4232b55e5b7b845b5119en +__is_running:1 - Filter : 
ExecuteQueryAgainstLucene (sitecore_testing_index): +__is_running:1 +SpanWildcardQuery(datasourceitems:*4b75d9f9081d4232b55e5b7b845b5119*) - Filter : 
ExecuteQueryAgainstLucene (sitecore_master_index): +_datasource:sitecore +(+(+_path:11111111111111111111111111111111 +_latestversion:1) +(+_templatename:base person +_path:4a14e57a73904438ac00e968863c3ea3)) - Filter : 
ExecuteQueryAgainstLucene (sitecore_master_index): +_datasource:sitecore +(+(+_path:11111111111111111111111111111111 +_latestversion:1) +(+_templatename:base person +_path:4a14e57a73904438ac00e968863c3ea3)) - Filter : 
ExecuteQueryAgainstLucene (sitecore_master_index): +_datasource:sitecore +(+(+_path:11111111111111111111111111111111 +_latestversion:1) +(+_templatename:base person +_path:4a14e57a73904438ac00e968863c3ea3)) - Filter : 
ExecuteQueryAgainstLucene (sitecore_master_index): +_datasource:sitecore +(+(+_path:11111111111111111111111111111111 +_latestversion:1) +(+_templatename:base person +_path:4a14e57a73904438ac00e968863c3ea3)) - Filter : 
ExecuteQueryAgainstLucene (sitecore_master_index): +_datasource:sitecore +(+(+_path:11111111111111111111111111111111 +_latestversion:1) +(+_templatename:client profile +_path:d2e3f7abdc384f2bb525437c5ae6364b)) - Filter : 
ExecuteQueryAgainstLucene (sitecore_master_index): +_datasource:sitecore +(+(+_path:11111111111111111111111111111111 +_latestversion:1) +(+_templatename:client profile +_path:d2e3f7abdc384f2bb525437c5ae6364b)) - Filter : 
ExecuteQueryAgainstLucene (sitecore_master_index): +_datasource:sitecore +(+(+_path:11111111111111111111111111111111 +_latestversion:1) +(+_templatename:client profile +_path:d2e3f7abdc384f2bb525437c5ae6364b)) - Filter : 
ExecuteQueryAgainstLucene (sitecore_master_index): +_datasource:sitecore +(+(+_path:11111111111111111111111111111111 +_latestversion:1) +(+_templatename:client profile +_path:d2e3f7abdc384f2bb525437c5ae6364b)) - Filter : 
ExecuteQueryAgainstLucene (sitecore_master_index): +_datasource:sitecore +(+(+_path:11111111111111111111111111111111 +_latestversion:1) +(+_templatename:tag +_path:4cbbae98f49846c1af336729558de117)) - Filter : 
ExecuteQueryAgainstLucene (sitecore_master_index): +_datasource:sitecore +(+(+_path:11111111111111111111111111111111 +_latestversion:1) +(+_templatename:tag +_path:4cbbae98f49846c1af336729558de117)) - Filter : 
ExecuteQueryAgainstLucene (sitecore_master_index): +_datasource:sitecore +(+(+_path:11111111111111111111111111111111 +_latestversion:1) +(+_templatename:client profile +_path:d2e3f7abdc384f2bb525437c5ae6364b)) - Filter : 
ExecuteQueryAgainstLucene (sitecore_master_index): +_datasource:sitecore +(+(+_path:11111111111111111111111111111111 +_latestversion:1) +(+_templatename:client profile +_path:d2e3f7abdc384f2bb525437c5ae6364b)) - Filter : 
ExecuteQueryAgainstLucene (sitecore_master_index): +_datasource:sitecore +(+(+_path:11111111111111111111111111111111 +_latestversion:1) +(+_templatename:client profile +_path:d2e3f7abdc384f2bb525437c5ae6364b)) - Filter : 
ExecuteQueryAgainstLucene (sitecore_master_index): +_datasource:sitecore +(+(+_path:11111111111111111111111111111111 +_latestversion:1) +(+_templatename:client profile +_path:d2e3f7abdc384f2bb525437c5ae6364b)) - Filter : 
ExecuteQueryAgainstLucene (sitecore_master_index): +_datasource:sitecore +(+(+_path:11111111111111111111111111111111 +_latestversion:1) +(+_path:154d56cc0de243c7bbc0a25bd7ffd901 +(+_path:154d56cc0de243c7bbc0a25bd7ffd901 +(-_group:154d56cc0de243c7bbc0a25bd7ffd901 +*:*)))) - Filter : 
ExecuteQueryAgainstLucene (sitecore_master_index): +_datasource:sitecore +(+(+_path:11111111111111111111111111111111 +_latestversion:1) +(+_path:154d56cc0de243c7bbc0a25bd7ffd901 +(+_path:154d56cc0de243c7bbc0a25bd7ffd901 +(-_group:154d56cc0de243c7bbc0a25bd7ffd901 +*:*)))) - Filter :
```

That is, the search results are filtered based on their templatename and path. I tried running the same search in Luke without any filtering, and I am getting thousands of search results.

In my Sitecore 9.1, SOLR-powered instance this doesn't happen - the Content Search returns thousands of entries and the Editor only shows the first 20 or so, of which often none is relevant to the Content Editor.

**QUESTION**

How can I filter the Content Editor search results (in a Sitecore 9.1 installation) by Template or any other arbitrary restriction?

Answer (score 1):

Please follow the below steps to perform Search Filter in Content Editor in Sitecore 9.1 and Solr:

[image: SearchFilter1]

[image: SearchFilter2]

[image: SearchFilter3]

[image: SearchFilter4]

Comment: Hi Sumit, I was talking about the global search, not about the folder search.

Comment: Global search as in from your custom code for site or in the Content Editor itself?

Comment: I'm talking about the search in the Content Editor: https://www.screencast.com/t/nxnM4xaEHH7A

Comment: Global search also can be performed using the way I showed but I do get your point. You want to filter the search results from the Search bar above the content tree